# Central equations in Latex

Tags: latex

I am struggling with positioning equations centrally in Latex. Whatever I try, equations always stay positioned in the left. I use the following packages:

```
   \usepackage{amsfonts}          
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}         
\usepackage{longtable} 

and the following settings
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0. cm} 
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0. cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.54 cm}   
\setlength{\textwidth}{16. cm}     
\setlength{\textheight}{24 cm}     
\setlength{\marginparsep}{3 mm}    
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1.5 cm}


\setlength{\parindent}{0 mm}       
\setlength{\parskip}{1.5ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
\setlength{\mathindent}{1 cm}
```

Anyone knows, what could be the problem and how to resolve it? Thanks

Comment: Equations are centred by default. Please make a compilable [mre] which allows us to reproduce you problem. Maybe you a class with left aligned equations?